# Creating Buttons Dynamically in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to create specified number of buttons dynamically, but the size of the buttons should match the window.
Eg. First I am creating 10 buttons dynamically then it should create 10 buttons on the window. But in the time When I am specifying 5 buttons then it should create 5 buttons and it should match the window, that is according to the number of buttons the size of the button should adjust with the window size.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? If possible, include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). We are not code monkeys.

Comment: What toolkit>? Contrary to @moonbeam we are invariably code monkeys.

Answer (score 3):

Which toolkit are you using? I'm going to assume you're using Swing or AWT.

In Swing and AWT, there is a thing called a *layout manager* that specifies how components are laid out. In this case, `BoxLayout` sounds perfect for what you're seeking to do.